# Keras - Dimensions must be equal when returnSequence is True

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I'm trying to build a model to predict 4 values based on a sequence of 3 observations, I.E:

If the following is the data

```
+--------------------------------+
|feature |feature |feature |Value|
+--------------------------------+
|0.1     |0.1     |0.1     |1    |
+--------------------------------+
|0.2     |0.2     |0.2     |2    |
+--------------------------------+
|0.3     |0.3     |0.3     |3    |
+--------------------------------+
|0.4     |0.4     |0.4     |4    |
+--------+--------+--------+-----+
```

I want to predict `[1,2,3,4]` based on

```
+--------------------------+
|feature |feature |feature |
+--------------------------+
|0.1     |0.1     |0.1     |
+--------------------------+
|0.2     |0.2     |0.2     |
+--------------------------+
|0.3     |0.3     |0.3     |
+--------+--------+--------+
```

My `X,y` shape are as follows `(1228, 3, 19) (1228, 4, 1)`

---

```
def get_model():
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(LSTM(32, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True, input_shape=(X.shape[1], X.shape[2]))),
  model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu')),
  model.add(Dense(4, activation='sigmoid'))

  model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer="adam", metrics=['mae', 'mse'])
  return model
```

---

```
My Model code:
Model: "sequential_17"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_17 (LSTM)               (None, 3, 32)             6656      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_34 (Dense)             (None, 3, 32)             1056      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_35 (Dense)             (None, 3, 4)              132       
=================================================================
Total params: 7,844
Trainable params: 7,844
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

When I try to fit the data:

```
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=200, batch_size=64, validation_split=0.2, verbose=0, callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 3 and 4 for
```

How should I reshape my data in order for this to work, should I pad the missing sequence?

Comment: How can your `X` be 3-dimensional? If you have 1228 samples of 3 features each (as in the example you show), its shape should be `(1228, 3)`; what is the 3rd dimension of 19? Similarly, the shape of your `y` should be just `(1228,)` (the *features* are not supposed to be part of the *value*).

Comment: It's 1228 groups of 3 days each with 19 features. In my question I simplified the data set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If understood correctly, for each example you have the following:

input -> (3,19)
output -> (4, 1)

where you are trying to regress 4 values based on 3 sequences of 19 values. If that is correct, then you could either use `return_sequences=False` in your model and reshape your outputs (y) to have a shape of (4,) rather than (4,1) like `y=np.squeeze(y, -1)`.  Or If you want to keep the sequence, use `TimeDistributed` and `GlobalAveragePooling1D` layers and do the same for the output. It would look like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True, input_shape=(3, 19))),
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(32, activation='relu')))
model.add(GlobalAveragePooling1D())
model.add(Dense(4, activation='sigmoid'))

model.summary()

Model: "sequential_9"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_9 (LSTM)                (None, 3, 32)             6656      
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_4 (TimeDist (None, 3, 32)             1056      
_________________________________________________________________
global_average_pooling1d_2 ( (None, 32)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_16 (Dense)             (None, 4)                 132       
=================================================================
Total params: 7,844
Trainable params: 7,844
Non-trainable params: 0
```

**EDITS**

The problem with your current model is that it expects your targets/outputs to have shape of `(3,4)` while your actual outputs have a shape of `(4,1)`